# How to speed up an incredibly slow loop through a List of

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following method which retrieves sales data from the db.

The Db returns the data in 1.5 to 1.9 seconds, which I'd like to be faster but one step at a time
I have to manipulate the data here in the method because I couldn't figure out how to return it in the final form from the query, which is certainly the most efficient way to do so.

Since the results (results type is a List of AuctionDatum )count is rarely going to be more than 1-200 results, I figured this method would suffice for now...NOT

The db runs as noted above BUT the loop takes almost 4-5 seconds, and for this testing it was only 25 records!! (4 of the 25 required conversion to $, I didnt measure that time for that method)

Method

```
public async Task<CarSalesData> GetCarSalesDataAsync(int modelId)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var results = await GetVehicleAuctionDataForModelAsync(modelId);
        var cnt = results.Count;
        var csd = new CarSalesData
        {
            ModelName =
                $"{results[0].Vehicle.Model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName} {results[0].Vehicle.Model.ModelYear} {results[0].Vehicle.Model.ModelName}"
        };
        var dates = new List<string>();
        var values = new List<double>();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elt = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        stopwatch.Start();
       
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            
            if (result.AuctionCurrency == "USD")
            {
                dates.Add(result.AuctionDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(result.SoldPrice));
            }
            else
            {
                dates.Add(result.AuctionDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(VehicleManagerHelpers.GetPriceInUSD(Convert.ToDecimal(result.SoldPrice), result.AuctionCurrency, result.AuctionDate))); }
            
        }

        csd.SaleDates = dates;
        csd.SalesValues = values;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elt1 = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        //the value of err below is:: The data retrieval method took 01.8641257 seconds and the loop took 05.5960528 seconds
        var err = $"The data retrieval method took {elt} seconds and the loop took {elt1} seconds";
        return csd;
    }
```

DB method

```
public async Task<IList<VehicleAuctionData>> GetVehicleAuctionDataForModelAsync(int modelId)
    {
        return await _context.AuctionDatum
            .Include(u => u.Vehicle)
            .Include(u => u.Vehicle.Model)
            .Include(u => u.Vehicle.Model.Manufacturer)
            .Where(u => u.Vehicle.ModelId == modelId && u.SoldPrice !=null)
            .OrderBy(u => u.AuctionDate)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Any help in getting this to run more efficiently would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `VehicleManagerHelpers.GetPriceInUSD` do?

Comment: @David L converts the non-USD prices to USD..the data comes from an xml file on Azure..It just returns the currency value and the method does the math

Comment: either that, there may be a latency in obtaining that xml file - may be worth to run another benchmark with the currency conversion temporarily removed; or the queryable makes roundtrips per each loop iteration. use ToList() to make sure it is done querying before the loop starts, and/or monitor the actual database activity with a profiler.

Comment: You need to track timing around each type of call.  Otherwise you won't be able to successfully identify the bottleneck.

Comment: @DavidL does the debugger do this automatically? I thought it did/could...

Comment: I had experience that for loops can be up to twice faster than foreach,

Comment: @AnGG that is very rarely the case unless some other allocation is occurring on the side.

Comment: @CaiusJard the debugger will modify execution time.  That's not a good way to profile.

Comment: I expect for these aeons it doesn't matter so much

Comment: Well it is the usd conversion...each run through it, and there are 5; takes .55-.6 seconds. Ill have to figure out a better way to do this. How can I return just the two lists from the db query? that will speed this up for sure.

Comment: It looks like you're only using a few properties from your results: manufacturer, auction date, auction currency, sold price. You could limit the data coming back from your query into a smaller view model / result object

Comment: You do realize that `elt1` is the combined time of the data retrieval *and* the loop, right? If you want to measure the loop separately, use `stopwatch.Restart()` (or call `stopwatch.Reset()` before `Start`).

Comment: @Jonathan  yes, but I can never get the syntax right for that in the query...suggestion?

Comment: does each call to `GetPriceInUSD` fetch your xml? If so, you could cache the exchange rates locally and refresh every X hours or whatever

Comment: For what it's worth, prices should be stored as `decimal`, not `double`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a few properties, create a model that contains those properties you need, and `select` into it. For example:

```
public async Task<IList<VehicleAuctionData>> GetVehicleAuctionDataForModelAsync(int modelId)
{
    return await _context.AuctionDatum
        .Include(u => u.Vehicle)
        .Include(u => u.Vehicle.Model)
        .Include(u => u.Vehicle.Model.Manufacturer)
        .Where(u => u.Vehicle.ModelId == modelId && u.SoldPrice !=null)
        .Select(u => new SmallerObject{
           Manufacturer = u.Vehicle.Model.Manufacturer.Name,
           AuctionDate = u.AuctionDate,
           AuctionCurrency = u.AuctionCurrency,
           // add properties as needed here
         })
        .OrderBy(u => u.AuctionDate)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

With Linq, the query will then be trimmed to only return those values needed to satisfy the output. Depending on how heavy your objects are, this might reduce the amount of data coming back from the db.